# Dynamically insert several entries into TitledPane?

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tabs, drag-and-drop

I'm attempting to insert several draggable entries into an `Accordion`'s `TitledPane` in JavaFX.

There is a class function `setContent` of the `TitledPane` class that I can call in Java, and I can provide it something like a `Label` to it, which will result in the single label being displayed as the single entry of the `TitledPane`, as such:

```
titledPane.setText("Test TitledPane");
titledPane.setContent(new Label("Test Label"));`
```

[image]

However, I'm looking to insert several entries into the `TitledPane`, not just one.

Every single tutorial on `TitledPane` and `Accordion` I saw only show how to create them with initial permanent values, and not how to dynamically insert values into them as needed.

How would I go about inserting several values into a `TitledPane` dynamically using Java? What label type would I need to make these entries in order to allow them to be draggable by the user's cursor?

Comment: Drag and drop is a different question from your title. Oracle provide a [tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/events-tutorial/drag-drop.htm) for the operation. You have to code the logic based on  events, there is no “label type” for such a thing.  Ask a new specific question if you have more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Content:**

1. Adding several items into a `TabPane`
2. Moving elements across the `UI` with the mouse

### **1. Several Items into Tab Pane**

If you want to insert several GUI components to a `titled pane`, you could create a separate LayoutContainer that contains all your desired GUI components and subsequently add it to your TitledPane using `setContent(LayoutContainer)`. Choose the layout that matches your desired design.

Example: Creating several components using a `VBox` for a simple design

```
TitledPane pane = new TitledPane();
pane.setText("Test TitledPane");
            
VBox box = new VBox(20);
box.getChildren().addAll(new Label("I am a Label"), new Button("I am a button"), new CheckBox("Click me"));
            
pane.setContent(box); //add the VBox with the elements to the Tab
            
            
Scene scene = new Scene(pane,500, 500);    scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("application.css").toExternalForm());
```

That's the result:

[image]

Now if you'd like your GUI to look more user-friendly, sophisticated and modern, you can still add more Layout Containers containing more components to the `Pane` by adding the Containers to other Containers.

### **2. Drag element across the screen**

In this example, I added just a `label` to the `TabPane`. Using this code, you can move the label as you wish across the entire `tab`.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.Tab;
import javafx.scene.control.TabPane;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    private double xOffset = 0;
    private double yOffset = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        primaryStage.setTitle("Draggable Tab with Label Example");

        TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();

        // Create a tab with a label
        Tab tab = new Tab("Draggable Tab");
        Pane tabContent = new Pane();

        Label label = new Label("Drag me");
        label.setStyle("-fx-background-color: lightblue; -fx-padding: 10px;");

        tabContent.getChildren().add(label);
        tab.setContent(tabContent);
        
        tabPane.getTabs().add(tab);

        Scene scene = new Scene(tabPane, 400, 300);

        label.setOnMousePressed(this::onMousePressed);
        label.setOnMouseDragged(this::onMouseDragged);
        label.setOnMouseReleased(this::onMouseReleased);

        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void onMousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
        xOffset = event.getSceneX() - ((Label) event.getSource()).getLayoutX();
        yOffset = event.getSceneY() - ((Label) event.getSource()).getLayoutY();
    }

    private void onMouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
        double x = event.getSceneX() - xOffset;
        double y = event.getSceneY() - yOffset;

        Label label = (Label) event.getSource();
        label.setLayoutX(x);
        label.setLayoutY(y);
    }

    private void onMouseReleased(MouseEvent event) {
        // Optionally, you can add cleanup code here
    }
}
```

You can apply this code to other elements by assigning the respective methods to your desired element.

Comment: Thanks for this clear answer, adding a `VBox` element allows me to insert several elements into the `TitledPane`.
One quick question; which one of the elements for the label entries within the `VBox` will allow me to drag it across the screen with my cursor?

Comment: Do you mean, that if I were to change the position of the `label`, I could just drag and drop it to another position?

Comment: I have added the second part of the answer. Using the provided code, you can enable moving an element across the UI.